# Show X and Y coordinates?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am not really sure of how to start this one off. 
Either way, I want to show x and y coordinates on a webpage when the mouse moves on the page. It also has to work with any browser.

Heres the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Coordinates</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="center">
             <h1>Mouse Coordinates</h1>
             <p>x-coordinate: </p><p id="xcord">0</p>
             <p>y-coordiante: </p><p id="ycord">0</p>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

CSS File:

```
#center{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;

}
```

JavaScript File:

Not much, not sure where to start off...

```
window.onload = init;

function init(e) {

}
```

Comment: [`onmousemove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onmousemove) and [`e.pageX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.pageX), [`e.pageY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.pageY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically you need to document.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemover, false); that references a function - mouseover() - that will get your clientX and clientY. From there you need to set innerHTML of your two p elements to those values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pageX and pageY something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('body').on('mousemove', function init(e) {
   $('#xcord').text(e.pageX);
   $('#ycord').text(e.pageY);
});
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j6AND/)

Comment: that would only get the coord once since its attached to onload, needs attached to onmousemove.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for assuming you are using JQuery.

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
        $("#xcord").html(e.pageX);
        $("#ycord").html(e.pageY);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zvm7s/2/

Hope it helps